# How to find files by user property

Tags: files, root, find

I need to print the files in /var directory which have "m" as first letter  . I did like that

```
find /var -type f -name "m*"
```

But the files' user must not be root. How can I add/do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo find /var -type f -name "m*" ! -user root
```

should do it. `!` negates `-user root` meaning not user root.

Comment: But this time the files on the screen don't start with letter m..

Comment: I did this test, it worked for me. Did you spell this command correctly?

Comment: yes but It says permission denied to a lot of files

Comment: Then you have to run it with ´sudo` .. I have updated my answer above.